# Text message forwarding not working on Mac

Tags: ios, mac, messages, sms

Just replaced my SIM card by a new one with the same number. Text message forwarding stopped working for me now.

- FaceTime calls working on my Mac and vice versa.
- iMessage works on Mac and vice versa.
- When i receive text message (SMS) it shows only on the iPhone, on Mac i get nothing.

Tried to reboot Mac, iPhone - didn't help. Tried to turn off iMessage in General settings, then turning it on doesn't help, but now i get "Waiting for activation..." below iMessage switcher.

So i can't use text messages on my Mac. Any suggestions?

Comment: Go to settings on your phone. Then to the "messages" settings panel, and find the text message forwarding area. Make sure that your Mac is listed as a device receiving text message forwarding. If it is not, set it up. If it is, try removing that device and setting it up again.

Comment: It is listed, but how to remove it?